# Cannot create directory on local network

Tags: c#, desktop, system.io.directory

```
string serverPath = GetServerDirectory(serverDirectory);
string fullPath = @Path.Combine(serverPath, "P00125");

if (!Directory.Exists(fullPath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
```

The `fullPath` should be: `"\\\\192.168.100.9\\98 PatientsScan\\P00125"`

But the actual value is: `"\\\\192.168.100.9\\98 PatientsScan"`

and the `Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);` throws the following exception:

> System.IO.PathTooLongException: 'The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.'

Comment: Why are your backslashes doubly-escaped?

Comment: and not quadruply-escaped?

Comment: Debug your code and find, what is returned by your function GetServerDirectory, so that you can see what is combined in the next line of code.

Comment: @Dai But are they? If this some output from the debugger, the "real-world" (UNC) path `\\192.168.100.9\98 PatientScan` would look exactly like shown, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Dai sorry for that, but i can't understand what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I'm curious about what exactly `@Path` is. Generally `System.IO.Path` would be either that or `Path` with `using System.IO`. `@Path` seems like it would usually be some other variable defined in this code. e.g. `var @Path = "some string"`.

Comment: @moreON Ignoring Razor `.cshtml`, the `@` prefix in C# is a way of escaping reserved keywords - it isn't significant in this case: `@Path` and `System.IO.Path` and `Path` are all equivalent.

Comment: on network share - you can not create a shared folder. use \\ip\SHAREDFOLDER\98 patient\... etc or \\ip\D$\dig to folder location\...
you cant create a shared folder, but you can create a folder  INSIDE shared folder

Comment: I cannot repro this https://dotnetfiddle.net/bkP955 if you have the correct base path in `serverPath` then `Combine` should work correctly. What is the actual value of `serverPath`?